# The configuration section 'system.ServiceModel' cannot be read, missing section declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am following the documentation from http://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds to set up a Nuget Server.  I have followed all the steps, but when I run VS I get the error above.  From the error I am missing a section, but what section am I missing and how do I add that section.  I have searched stack and google and have been unable to find an answer.  Here is the code for the web.config

```
?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key ="packagePath" value="E:\HostedNugetServer"/>
    </appSettings>
  <system.ServiceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    </system.ServiceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be just a typo in your post, but your system Service Model declaration should be with a lower-case "s" on the serviceModel.

```
<system.serviceModel>
     <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: If this solved the problem, you should mark abrown's answer as correct, @Aaron.